# Using a (logical) vector from a reactive expression in a reactive context / attempt to apply non-function error

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am trying to use a logical vector from a reactive expression. This generates an error in a function xor() when I try to perform a logical operation on this vector in another reactive expression. I would like to generate a reactive expression (logical vector), and then use it in another reactive function. A toy example below. The error appears when points on the plot are clicked.

In the original [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-excluding-points.html), keeprows() is not reactive, but I would like to make this structured as on the schematic below (from Shiny website). The fist object is input for a reactive expression, and then a second (reactive) object (which is a user-subsetted table) is used for point selection, etc. The elements after bifurcation are the tables with the kept and excluded points. I have a problem in making this last subsetting to work.

[image]

Could someone explain to me the root of this problem?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,
                      click = "plot1_click",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush"
                      )
           ),
           actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle points"),
           sliderInput(inputId = "efficiency", value = 20, label = "MPG", min = min(mtcars$mpg), max = max(mtcars$mpg))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # For storing which rows have been excluded

  mt_subset <- reactive(mtcars %>% filter(mpg > input$efficiency))

  vals <- reactiveValues()
  vals$keeprows <- reactive(rep(TRUE, nrow(mt_subset()), label = "TuProblem", quoted = FALSE))

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    # Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
    keep    <- mt_subset()[ vals$keeprows(), , drop = FALSE]
    exclude <- mt_subset()[!vals$keeprows(), , drop = FALSE]

    ggplot(keep, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
      geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.5, 5.5), ylim = c(5,35))
  })

  # Toggle points that are clicked
  observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
    res <- nearPoints(mt_subset(), input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)

    vals$keeprows <- xor(as.logical(vals$keeprows()), as.logical(res$selected_))
  })

  # Toggle points that are brushed, when button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
    res <- brushedPoints(mt_subset(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)

    vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows(), res$selected_)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Adding `keeprows` to `vals` makes it reactive, I believe.
 
From `?reactiveValues`: This function returns an **object for storing reactive values**. It is similar to a list, but with special capabilities for reactive programming. When you read a value from it, the calling reactive expression takes a reactive dependency on that value, and when you write to it, it notifies any reactive functions that depend on that value. Note that **values taken from the reactiveValues object are reactive**, but the reactiveValues object itself is not.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. My goals is to create `data.table` based on user input. A plot will be generated based on the data in this `data.table`. I would like to give a user the option of selecting (and de-selecting points), and thereby splitting the `data.table` into two subsets (kept rows and excluded rows). Basically, the only difference compared to the original example is that the input `data.table` used for `NearPoints()` needs to be reactive. If there's an alternative way to do it, I will be happy to learn.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're getting at. Do you want the same functionality in the Rshiny example, where the selected points are greyed out and the correlation changes? That will be the same regardless of whether you read the data in or use built-in data.

Comment: Ok, sorry for not being clear on that. I expanded the question in order to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the output you're looking for, but this code reads in a local file and then performs the brushing point selection, greying out the brushed points after "toggle points" is hit and also adjusting the correlation.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)   # For nicer ggplot2 output when deployed on Linux
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

data(iris)
write.xlsx(x = iris, file = "iris.xlsx")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    fileInput(inputId = "file",
              label = "Load file"),
    column(width = 6,
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,
                      click = "plot1_click",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush"
                      )
           ),
           actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle points"),
           actionButton("exclude_reset", "Reset")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Get file
  getFile <- reactive({ if (is.null(input$file)) {
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    return(input$file)
  }})

  # Read data
  data <- reactive({ if (is.null(getFile())) {
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    as.data.frame(read_excel(getFile()$datapath))
  }})

  # For storing which rows have been excluded
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(data(), {
    vals$keeprows <- rep(T, nrow(data()))
  })

  # Toggle points that are clicked
  observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
    res <- nearPoints(data(), input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)

    vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
  })

  # Toggle points that are brushed, when button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
    res <- brushedPoints(data(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)

    vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
  })

  # Reset all points
  observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
    vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(data()))
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(data())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {

      # Indices for keep and exclude
      keep_v <- which(vals$keeprows)
      exclude_v <- which(!vals$keeprows)

      # Subset data
      keep <- data()[keep_v, , drop = F]
      exclude <- data()[exclude_v, , drop = F]

      ggplot(keep, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() +
        geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
        geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25)

    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's very useful. However, in this case, the user will only modify the data using widgets. I modified the example in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,
                      click = "plot1_click",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush"
                      )
           ),
           actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle points"),
           sliderInput(inputId = "efficiency", value = 20, label = "MPG", min = min(mtcars$mpg), max = max(mtcars$mpg))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mt_subset <- reactive(mtcars %>% filter(mpg > input$efficiency))
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(mt_subset(), {
  vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(mt_subset()), label = "TuProblem", quoted = FALSE)
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    # Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
    keep    <- mt_subset()[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
    exclude <- mt_subset()[!vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
    ggplot(keep, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
      geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.5, 5.5), ylim = c(5,35))
  })
  observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
    res <- nearPoints(mt_subset(), input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)
    vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
  })

  observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
    res <- brushedPoints(mt_subset(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)

    vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```